# Equilibrium of a body with potential energy as a function of position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, calculus

We know that if the potential energy of a body, say $U(x)$ of a body is known as a function of its x-coordinate, for equilibrium, $$\frac{dU(x)}{dx} = 0$$ Also, several sources suggest that for the state of neutral equilibrium, $$\frac{d^2U(x)}{dx^2} = 0$$
I understand that the sources try to convey that neutral equilibrium is established when the $U \space vs\space  x$ curve is parallel to the x-axis over an interval. But, in cases such as $U(x) = kx^3$, we find that $\frac{d^2U(x)}{dx^2} = 0$ when $x = 0$ but clearly it is a point of inflexion as opposed to a straight line parallel to the x-axis.

[image]

Here, we see that at the origin, force is obviously zero, so equilibrium is attained. Now my question is what kind of equilibrium is this? I felt like it should be an unstable equilibrium as the body once displaced some $\delta > 0$ distance away from $x = 0$, eventually will cross the mean position and experience a force always directing it away from the mean position. However, this argument still doesn't convince me enough.

Also, in the case of $U(x) = kx^4$, we see that the origin is a point of minima and hence a region of stable equilibrium although $\frac{d^2U(x)}{dx^2} = 0$. So, is this method of checking for the type of equilibrium in a body accurate as it gets contradicted in places like these? If not, how exactly can we check the type of equilibrium in a body given potential energy as a function of position analytically and without plotting the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

for the equilibrium state you obtain this linear differential equation

$$ m\ddot x_l+c\,x_l=0\tag 1$$

where $~x_l~$ is the linearized state and
$$ c=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{x=x_0}$$

is the spring constant and

$~x_0~$ is the linearization point

now if $~c=0~$ from equation (1)
$~m\ddot x_l=0~$ this means  that you have "mass without spring ", there is no equilibrium state in this case .

---

[image]

Lets write it like this $$~m\,\ddot x=F(x)~$$ where $~F(x)~$ is nonlinear force function . take the Taylor series at point $~x_0~$ you obtain

$$m\ddot x=F(x_0)+F'(x_0)\,(x-x_0)$$

thus the static Equilibrium  ($~x_s~$ )

$$0=F(x_0)+F'(x_0)\,(x_s-x_0)\quad\Rightarrow x_s\\
F'(x_0)= \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{x=x_0}$$

this means that if $~F'(x_0)=0~$ , you can't obtain  the static equilibrium position $~x_s~$

Comment: I couldn't understand why there will be no equilibrium, as the force will be zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: See new  document

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I kind of understood what you were trying to say but could you explain the basic ideas or reference where I can learn about the ideas mentioned here as I am a highschool student and don't really know some the concepts used here

Comment: Lets look at your example , the EOM $~ \ddot x=-\frac{d U}{dx}=-3\,k\,x^2 =F(x)~$. this is a nonlinear differential equation . how you obtain a linear differential equation ?. first linearized the force function at point $~x_0~$ , you obtain $~F_L(x)=-3\,k\,x_0^2-6\,k\,x_0(x-x_0)~$  from here is equilibrium point is $~ \ddot x=0=F_L(x)\quad,\Rightarrow, x=\frac 12 x_0~$ so the linear  differential equation is $~\ddot{x}_L=-F(x=x_0)\,x_L=-\frac 34 k\,x_0^2\,x_L~$ . you obtain the static equilibrium only if $~x_0\ne 0~$. if $~x_0=0~$ the differential equation is $~\ddot{x}_L=0~$

Answer (score 0):

The force acting is minus the potential gradient, ie minus the gradient of your graph.
Other than at $x=0$ the gradient of the graph is always positive and so the force is always in the negative $x$ direction ie to the left.

Thus no matter in which direction you displace the body it will experience a force to the left and not stop/oscillate about $x=0$ but rather move to the left, hence it is a position of unstable equilibrium.